# How to extract multiple values into select form and then add them again into new table?

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

```
//Connects to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DB);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Connection error " . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (isset($_POST['points']) & isset($_POST['user'])) {
    if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO penalty (user_id, first_name, last_name, name, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"))){
        echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if(!($stmt->bind_param("sssss",$_POST['points'],$_POST['user']))){
        echo "Bind failed: " . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Execute failed: " . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    } else {
        $stmt->close();
        header('Location: GivePoints1.php');
        echo "Added successfully";
        exit();
    }

    $stmt->close();

}
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="GivePoints1.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Penalty:</label>
        <select name="points[]" id="points">
            <?php

            //Prepare SELECT statement for user's name
            if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, value FROM points"))){
                echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
            }

          
            //Execute the SELECT statement
            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            //Bind values to variables
            if(!$stmt->bind_result($name, $value)){
                echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            //Output name
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo'<option value=" '.$name.' "> '.$name.' - ' . $value .' Pts </option>';
            }

            $stmt->close();
            ?>
            </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Give To:</label>
        <select name="user[]" id="user">
            <?php

            //Prepare SELECT statement for user's name
            if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM award_user"))){
                echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
            }

          
            //Execute the SELECT statement
            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            //Bind values to variables
            if(!$stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name, $last_name)){
                echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            //Output name
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo'<option value=" '.$id.' "> '.$first_name.' ' . $last_name .' </option>';
            }

            $stmt->close();
            ?>
            </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary ">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can someone guide me to the right road?

I need to add those values into new table where id  would be user_id (id extracted from award_user table change into user_id in penalty table)

I need to inser id - as user_id, first_name, last_name, name and value into table penalty. it prints select no problem but wouldn't add anything to new table

im trying to do it for a good while now and no luck. i will appriciate some explanation

Comment: Why would you need to insert the first name and last name into the `penalty` table?? Just insert the user ID, that is enough to identify the user. You already know their details as stored in the user table. You can JOIN the tables together in a query whenever you want to view the combined information. This is a basic principle of relational database design - don't duplicate any data. Use the foreign key relationship the way it was intended, instead. I can make the same suggestion again, in terms of what you insert from the points table - ie. just insert the ID into penalty.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, please bring your error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should **never** be echoing error data deliberately, it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you I got it sorted with your help! However i got different problem now: ````` if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, value FROM penalty INNER JOIN award_user ON penalty.user_id = award_user.id INNER JOIN points ON penalty.points_id = points.id WHERE penalty.user_id = award_user.id;"))){
 ````i need to show results that are only associated with the user for example if user id = 1 then will only show to user which id is 1 and so on. with that statement i can see all points assigned to all users. Can you help?

Comment: How about `WHERE penalty.user_id = 1` ??

Comment: @ADyson This way im getting all the points assigned to user id= 1. But i have 60 users in database.

Comment: Well...you asked how to get the results associated only with user ID 1, so I told you. Was your real question a slightly different one?

Comment: @ADyson Got it i added `$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["user_id"]);` and id = ? all good in the hood

Comment: @ADyson When  I have that `if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO penalty (user_id, points_id) VALUES (?, ?);")))` And points_id takes the values from table `points`  `name,value` how can i now in 1 query update table `award_user` to reduce `balance` by the value from `points` table ?

Comment: Well, you can JOIN within an UPDATE query, so that should help you...

Comment: But why are you storing the balance separately? You can just calculate it surely when you need it - it's the initial total minus the sum of all the points entries for that user, I presume? Again another rule in database design generally is not to store values you can calculate, unless it's important for performance reasons for example (see [Bad Practice to Store Calculated Data in Database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database))

Comment: @ADyson i could do that but i need to reset the values every 7 days back to starting point so lets say if Man starts with 16 points and within 7 days he will go down to 0 then at the beginning of next week he will have 16 points again.

Comment: Date-stamping the records in the penalty table would probably help you with that

Comment: @ADyson Hi I'm trying to get that up and running (trying to get the right values out) `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT AU.id, AU.first_name, AU.last_name, AU.email, AU.total - points.value, AU.penalty FROM award_user AU INNER JOIN points LEFT JOIN penalty ON penalty.points_id = points.id AND penalty.user_id = AU.id;");` how ever what im getting is multiple records of one user into table and every signle penalty deducted separetly starting from 16 i getting 13 | 13 | 0| 10 and so on. that for all users instead of get that count up together and deduct from total to show one recordforuser